# How to grab the DeliveredEvent type via SOAP

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, fuel-sdk, email-tracking

So i've been able to grab the opens,clicks,sents and bounces pretty easily.  But I don't see separate object for delivered.  After doing some searching, I just assumed that salesforce doesn't have a delivered event.  But when I look at the EventType object, I see a DeliveredEvent, but no real way to access this event. [image]

Anyone have an idea of how to retrieve the DeliveredEvent for an email send?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

"DeliveredEvent" may be quoted as a member of the EventType enumeration, but there's no DeliveredEvent tracked in SFMC. Delivered = Sent - Bounced.